# What wavelength of light is the term 'focal length' defined against?

Tags: optics, visible-light, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, lenses

Because different wavelengths of light are bent differently in a medium, the focal length ought to be different for each of them (which is why white light splits up into a rainbow). If I have a "25 mm focal length lens", it will focus red light at a different length then say, X-rays. So which wavelength of light is 'focal length' defined by?

Comment: Whatever the data sheet of the lens says.

Comment: @CuriousOne No one includes anything about light wavelength. That's why I asked.

Comment: You need to change your lens vendor, they are not a professional supplier.

Comment: @CuriousOne Ok, I looked up ThorLabs, and they measure the *back focal length* of a lens with the wavelength of pure yellow light; but they don't say anything about the actual focal length. Why? http://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=256

Comment: You have to ask the CEO of ThorLabs that question, we are not responsible for the quality of their spec sheets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although it's a good question it's not one we can answer. It is down to the manufacturer/supplier to decide how to describe the dispersion of their lenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if no further information is given, you can assume that the focal length is approximately correct for the visible spectrum. Note that, in your example, since the focal length is specified as 25 mm, as long as the FL is within 0.5 mm of 25 mm the lens is within spec. Even with window glass, you should be able to get this performance from 400 nm to 700 nm for a simple lens.